# A numerical solution for $ x^2 y''(x)+a(x)y'(x)+b(x)y(x)=0$ with $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=1$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

> Considering the following equation
> $$ x^2 y''(x)+a(x)y'(x)+b(x)y(x)=0$$
> with $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=1$.
>
> How could I find numerically a solution?
>
> Here $a(x=0)$ and $b(x=0)$ are 2 complex constants.

What I tried is, to start at $x=\epsilon$ from which I'm getting a solution and I tried to reduce the value of $\epsilon$ to check the convergence of the solution. The solution is strongly dependent on the value of $\epsilon$.

I've seen similar problems, known as singular perturbation boundary layer problem. Any idea on how to solve these type of equations?

Comment: These equations are called *ODE* with regular singularities or Fuchsian ODEs: for a minimal introduction to the subject, see [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fuchsian_equation)

Comment: @DanieleTampieri : For a regular singularity, you need $a(0)=0$, so that the whole equation can be considered a perturbation of the Euler-Cauchy equation $x^2y''(x)+a'(0)xy'(x)+b(0)y(x)=0$.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri: This equation looks more like singular perturbation problem, only that the coefficient in front y''(x) is not a small constant value.

Comment: @LutzL: you're right. I apologize for my imprecise quotation: quoting by memory without having a working knowledge leads to this.

Comment: Tim, you're right. However, since you are searching for a numerical solution, why not determining a fundamental solution for the Cauchy problem of a part of the given equation and then study the integral equation which results by calculating the convolution of this solution with the full equation?